# Not able to train Resnet model with tripletloss, while VGG16 works, why?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, face-recognition, triplet

I am trying to do a transfer learning with ResNet50V2 model using triplet loss function. I have kept Include_top = False, input shape = (160,160,3) with Imagenet weights. The last 3 layers of my model is shown in the below image with 6 million trainable parameters.

[image]

During the training process, I could see the loss function values reducing from 7.6 to 0.8 but the accuracy does not improve. But when I replace the model with VGG16 and while training the last 3 layers, the accuracy improves from 50% to 90% along with loss value reducing from 6.0 to 0.5.

Where am I going wrong ? Is there anything specific I should look at while training resnet model ? How to train the resnet model ?